# What's the point of letting server to compile and minify assets when we can do it manually?

Tags: compilation, webserver, minify

*Disclaimer: I know almost nothing about servers. Sorry if this question doesn't make sense in the first place.*

I'm building my project in Node.js with CoffeeScript and Stylus and some other compiled stuff. Until now I've made a script to compile my code into regular JavaScript and CSS, then run it. I'm planning to upload the compiled assets to the production server, so there's no trace of CoffeeScript or Stylus anywhere afterward.

But I know that it's possible to directly run server-side CoffeeScript (`coffee app.coffee`), and that there are middlewares in Node which compile and minify client-side CoffeeScript and Stylus on the fly.

My question is, why let the server do it each time, instead of compiling the code ourselves? Wouldn't the first option add more strain on the server for no reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would not add strain on the server. An educated guess would tell me that one it compiles and minifies your CoffeeScript it caches the result for each subsequent request.

Manual processes introduce risk and probability of error.

Comment: So that's it? There's no visible advantage to manually compiling the stuff myself? Also, I get that it caches static assets (I'll look into it), but what about running CoffeeScript directly on the server-side? I don't think there's any caching there.

Comment: One advantage to advance compilation is that you checked your code and discovered errors before you deployed.